how to preserve all spacing with 'sed' when inserting content in a file
I have a shell variable with the following content:
Var="    a b   c"

and the following ASCII file 'file.txt'
line-1
line-2
line-3

I would like to insert the content of $Var after the 2nd line in the file using 'sed' but preserve all spacings. I.e. I want to end up with:
line-1
line-2
    a b   c
line-3

However, 'sed' doesn't preserve spacing at the beginning, and produces:
line-1
line-2
a b   c
line-3

What do I need to modify in the command input so that 'sed' also preserves spacings at the beginning? This is what I tried and this failed:
sed -i "2i $Var" file.txt
sed -i "2i\\$Var" file.txt


According to the sed documentation:

a\ - Appending text after a line.
i\ - Immediately output the lines of text which follow this command.


You could use 2a instead of 2i to append the line after the second line.
sed -i "2a\\$Var" file.txt

The contents of file.txt afterwards:
line-1
line-2
    a b   c
line-3


Thanks, your solution works! But in the meantime, I also realized that I am loosing leading spacings in the shell itself, in the construct while read Var; do ... done < someFile.txt . I will seek answer to this one on a Bash mailing list. Thanks a lot again!

@user9751447 while read Var needs to be while IFS= read -r Var to preserve leading/trailing white space and not interpret backslashes. See why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and make sure to copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix any issues it tells you about. There's a very good chance you should be using awk for this anyway, though, instead of a shell read loop calling sed.

These sed features are not very portable, the behavior and the permitted syntax varies between versions. More reasons why Ed is right.

@EdMorton Thanks! I am using while + read only to parse simple and small files, but for anything more complicated, indeed I am parsing with 'awk'

You're welcome. FYI calling awk would be simpler, clearer, briefer, more portable and more efficient for simple, small files too. The time when you need a while-read loop (or some other shell construct) is if you need to call other tools with each input line to do something other than text processing, not when you need to do text processing with small/simple input.

Consider using ed to edit a file instead.
$ cat file.txt
line-1
line-2
line-3
$ printf '2a\n%s\n.\nwq\n' "$Var" | ed file.txt
21
33
$ cat file.txt
line-1
line-2
    a b   c
line-3

ed takes the commands to execute as a series of lines on standard input.

2a: Enter input mode and append the entered text after line 2 of the current file.
. ends input mode
wq saves the current file and exits ed.


This might work for you (GNU sed & shell):
sed '2r /dev/stderr' 2<<<"$Var" file

Attach $Var to stderr using a here-string and read it into sed using the filename /dev/stderr.
Using stderr has the advantage that if file may be replaced by a piped in stdin i.e.
cat file | sed '2r /dev/stderr' 2<<<"$Var"

would also achieve the same result.
